# im having trouble making a OneToOne chat application inside the MultiThreaded code

Tags: java

is there a function i can use for making a private chat between two user without messing up my multi-threaded code?

CLIENT CLASS

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private BufferedWriter bufferedwriter;
    private String username;
    
    public Client(Socket socket, String Username) throws IOException{
    try{ 
    this.socket = socket;    
    this.bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    this.bufferedwriter =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    this.username = Username;
   } catch (IOException ex) {closeEverything( socket, bufferedReader,bufferedwriter);}
  }

 public void sendMsg() throws IOException{   /*block op.*/

 try{
 bufferedwriter.write(username);
 bufferedwriter.newLine();
 bufferedwriter.flush();
 
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 while (socket.isConnected()){
 String msgToSend = scanner.nextLine();
 bufferedwriter.write(username +": " + msgToSend);
 bufferedwriter.newLine();
 bufferedwriter.flush();
 
 }
 } catch (IOException ex) {closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader,bufferedwriter);}

 }
 public void ListenToMsg(){ /*block op.*/
 new Thread (new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
       String  MsgFromGC; 
       while (socket.isConnected()){
       try{
      MsgFromGC = bufferedReader.readLine();
      System.out.println(MsgFromGC);
        } catch (IOException ex) {closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader,bufferedwriter);}
       }
     }
 }).start();
 }
public void listenToPrivateMsg() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            String msgFromServer;
            try {
                while (socket.isConnected()) {
                    msgFromServer = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (msgFromServer.startsWith("PRIVATE|")) {
                        System.out.println(msgFromServer);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedwriter);
            }
        }).start();
    }
public void startPrivateChat() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the username to start a private chat: ");
    String receiverUsername = scanner.nextLine();

    while (socket.isConnected()) {
        String message = scanner.nextLine();
        String privateMessage = username + "(Private): " + message;

        try {
            bufferedwriter.write(privateMessage);
            bufferedwriter.newLine();
            bufferedwriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedwriter);
        }
    }
}
public void closeEverything(Socket socket, BufferedReader bufferedReader, BufferedWriter bufferedwriter) {  
try {
      if (bufferedReader != null) {
          bufferedReader.close();
        }
      if (bufferedwriter != null) {
            bufferedwriter.close();
        }
      if (socket != null) {
          socket.close();
        }
}catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Username for the chat: ");
    String username = scanner.nextLine();

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
    Client client = new Client(socket, username);
    System.out.println("Choose an option:");
    System.out.println("1. Join the public chat");
    System.out.println("2. Start a private chat");
    client.ListenToMsg();
    int option = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine(); 
    
    if (option == 1) {
        client.sendMsg(); 
    } else if (option == 2) {
        client.listenToPrivateMsg();
        client.startPrivateChat();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid option. Exiting...");
    }
  } 
}
```

CLIENT HANDLER CLASS

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

    
    public static ArrayList<ClientHandler> clientHandler = new ArrayList<>(); 
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    BufferedWriter bufferedwriter;
    String clientUsername;
    
   public  ClientHandler (Socket socket){ try {
   this.socket = socket;
   this.bufferedwriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
   this.bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
   this.clientUsername = bufferedReader.readLine();
   clientHandler.add(this);
   broadcastMessage("SERVER: " + clientUsername + " Has entered the chat");
   
   } catch (IOException ex) {closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedwriter);}
   }
    @Override
    public void run() { /*block op.*/
    String msgFromClient;
    while(socket.isConnected()){
        try {
            msgFromClient = bufferedReader.readLine();
            broadcastMessage(msgFromClient);
        } catch (IOException ex) {closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader,bufferedwriter); break;}
    }  
}
    
public void sendPrivateMessage(String receiverUsername, String message) throws IOException {
    for (ClientHandler clientHandler : clientHandler) {
        if (clientHandler.clientUsername.equals(receiverUsername)) {
            clientHandler.bufferedwriter.write("PRIVATE|" + message);
            clientHandler.bufferedwriter.newLine();
            clientHandler.bufferedwriter.flush();
        }
    }
} 
    
    
public void broadcastMessage(String MsgToSend) {
        for(ClientHandler clientHandler: clientHandler){
            try{
            if (!clientHandler.clientUsername.equals(clientUsername)){
            clientHandler.bufferedwriter.write(MsgToSend);
            clientHandler.bufferedwriter.newLine();
            clientHandler.bufferedwriter.flush();
            }
         } catch (IOException ex) {closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader,bufferedwriter); }
       }
    }



public void RemoveCH(){
clientHandler.remove(this);
broadcastMessage("SERVER: "+ clientUsername + " Has left the chat");

}
    public void closeEverything(Socket socket, BufferedReader bufferedReader, BufferedWriter bufferedwriter) {
    RemoveCH();

    try {
      if (bufferedReader != null) {
          bufferedReader.close();
        }
      if (bufferedwriter != null) {
            bufferedwriter.close();
        }
      if (socket != null) {
          socket.close();
        }
        }catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void sendMessage(String message) { }
}
```

SERVER CLASS

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Map<String, ClientHandler> connectedClients = new HashMap<>();
    public Server(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
        
    }
    
      public void startServer () throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      try{
      while (!serverSocket.isClosed()){
      Socket socket;
      socket = serverSocket.accept();    
      System.out.println("New client connected!!!");
      ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(socket);
      Thread thread = new Thread(clientHandler);
      thread.start();
      }
      
      } catch (IOException ex) {}
      }
      
public void closeServerSocket() {
try {
      if (serverSocket != null) {
      serverSocket.close();

}     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();}

}

     public static void main(String [] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     ServerSocket serverSocket;
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);    
     Server server = new Server (serverSocket);
     server.startServer();
} 
    public synchronized void startPrivateChat(String senderUsername, String receiverUsername, String message) {
        ClientHandler sender = connectedClients.get(senderUsername);
        ClientHandler receiver = connectedClients.get(receiverUsername);

        if (sender != null && receiver != null) {
            receiver.sendMessage(senderUsername + " (Private): " + message);
            sender.sendMessage(senderUsername + " (Private): " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

i tried everything and it doesn't work, it always sends the message to everyone not just the receiver and the group chat message also reaches the private conversation

Comment: In my view, this should be developed using MQ (Message Queues) instead which will serve what you need also, do some research on how big applications are working like WhatsApp and others there are bunch of applications

Comment: it's a project for my uni, we're required to do it using java and im really stuck

Comment: RMQ is also java-implementation see this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq